# corrupted file text while reading

Tags: java, io, buffer, inputstream

I have the following code:

```
BlobDomain blobDomain = null;
OutputStream out = null;
try {
    blobDomain = new BlobDomain();
    out = blobDomain.getBinaryOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer, 0, 8192)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        String line = (new String(buffer));
        fullText += line;
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    //do nothing
}finally{            
    if (out != null)
        try {
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

when i print the fullText what i see for larger files is that end part of the text is added again to the fullText. So full text has some lines repeated in the end. any suggestions on what is wrong here?

Comment: `new String(buffer)` uses the whole buffer.

Comment: You need to supply more arguments to limit how much of the buffer it uses.

Comment: By the way, this won't work if one of the `read` calls finishes in the middle of a multi-byte character.

Comment: sorry what would be the fix as i would not know the right buffer size

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you are getting this is that you are writing the entire buffer every time to your String. Thus, when you reach the end of the file you may not have read exactly the amount of bytes that your buffer is sized at. The old data is still in the buffer and will also be written to your String.

One option to solve this may be to write your data to a String first and then to write your String to the output stream. This should also be faster than adding to a String after each read.

Save inputStream to String:

```
java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(in).useDelimiter("\\A");
fullText = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
```

Write String to output stream:

```
out.write(fullText.getBytes());
```

If you want to keep you code as-is then perform a substring on the buffer and retrieve only the amount of bytes read. For example:

```
String line = (new String(buffer.substring(0,bytesRead));
```